# Must the Tikkun Hatsot be said on the floor?

Tags: tikkun-chatzot

Is there ever a heter le'hatchila *not* to say it on the floor?

(The action would presumably have *some* significance bediavad if not on the floor, but that is merely an assumption.)

Comment: There is no mitzvah to my knowledge to recite Tikkun Chatzos, it's all merely minhag. So there is no question of "lechatchila" and "bedieved" in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be that the *sitting on the floor* custom does not appear in the [Tur](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.1.1?lang=he), [Bet Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.1.13.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) or even the [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 1:2-3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.1.2?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) or its commentators.

It would seem from this that it can be said while seated normally.

The custom to sit on the floor seems to originate from the Ari z" l, as is mentioned in the [Kaf HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.1.2?lang=he&p2=Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.1.19.1&lang2=he).

But note that he says in the name of the Ben Ish Chai to **not** sit directly on the floor; but to have some separation like a piece of cloth to sit on.

You can see Sefardim sit on the steps going up to the Aaron HaKodesh and Bimah, when they say Tikun Chatzos before (or after) Mincha during the 9 days.

Here's the relevant parts of the Kaf HaChaim I referred to.

> יט) **זה סדר אמירת תיקון חצות ע"פ דברי רבינו האר"י ז"ל** בשער הכוו' בדרושי הלילה דרוש ת"ח דרוש א' בתחלת תי' רחל צריך שתלך ותשב אצל הפתח סמוך למזוזה ותסיר המנעלים ותשב יחף ותעטוף ראשך כאבל ותרבה בבכיה כפי כוחך (ועיין בזוה"ק פ' בשלח נ"ה ע"ב שכתב דכל ב"נ דבכי וארים קליה על חרבן ביתיה דקב"ה זכיה למה דכתיב לבתר יחדו ירננו וזכי למחמי ליה בישובא בחדוותא עכ"ל) ותקח אפר מקלה ותשים על מצתך במקום הנחת תפילין גם **תכוף ראשך ותחבק פניך בקרקע ממש** ותכוין בזה על שריפת התורה שנעשית אפר וגם תכוין איך מיום שנחרב ביה"מ ונשרפה התורה נמסרו סודותיה ורזיה לחיצונים וזה נקרא גלות התורה בעה"ר:‏
> ... < snip > ...
>   יט) וכתב הרה"ג בן איש חי שם אות ט' **שקודם שיאמר תיקון רחל יפרוש מטפחת או בגד אחד קל על הקרקע כדי שיעור מושבו דאין לישב על הקרקע ממש** וטוב שיהיה הפתח של החדר שהוא קורא בו פתוח אם אין שם קרירות:‏